# mysqli fetch_assoc dropping first line with foreach

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I'm trying to update one of my webpages from mysql commands to mysqli and everything works except for the output of my records.  It skips the first line. There should be 124 records, which I verify with

```
$NumCols = $RecordSet->num_rows;
Print($NumCols . "<br/>");
```

However, only 123 records print using the following code:

```
// Fill the first row of the table with the field names
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($RecordSet);
foreach($row as $column => $value) {
   Print("<td>" . $column . "</td>");
}
Print("</tr>");

// Fill the remaining rows of the table with the values
// This code is dropping the first result
$Pos = 1;
While($row1 = $RecordSet->fetch_assoc())
{
   Print("<tr><td>$Pos</td>");
   foreach($row1 as $column => $value) {
      Print("<td>" . $value . "</td>");
   }
   Print("</tr>");
   $Pos++;
}
```

I have tried without the while loop and that just prints a single record with each value as a new row. I have also tried to just print the row without a foreach statement and that just displayed the word Array 123 times and still skipped the first line. I have also tried to change the row variable in the while loop from row to row1 and both results give me the same missing first result.

I also verify the first line is missing when comparing the output from my mysql page to the mysqli page.

Comment: `num_rows` doesn't always return the correct number of rows.  How many rows do you get if you run the same query directly in mysql client, without php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You fetch the first line for the table header.
You could reset the internal pointer of the result set, just before the while loop:

```
$RecordSet->data_seek(0);
while($row1 = $RecordSet->fetch_assoc())
```

Comment: Thanks!  This did the trick.  I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($RecordSet);
```

this is fetching the first record, so the fetch_assoc() of the while-loop can't fetch it.
You might want to switch to a [do-while loop](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php).